# Отправка формы с HTTPS

Tags: php, html5

Когда отправляешь форму

```
    <form method="get" action="https://domain.org/confirm.php">
```

Теряется защищенное соединение
[image: NOT SECURED]

Как быть?

Comment: Значит на 'domain.org', который вы зачем-то прячете (как будто это сверхсекретное нечто, находящееся в публичном доступе), проблема с сертификатом или https

Comment: Или значит что на https-странице `/confirm` есть какая-то ссылка на http-ресурс (и, возможно, форма здесь вообще ни при чём)

Comment: да, форма скорее всего не при чём, такое может быть, если на страницу загружены какие-нибудь ресурсы не по https, например картинка. Откройте исходный код страницы и проверьте все атрибуты src, если в них явное указание http протокола